# RESTful approach for updating resource and creating associated objects

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, idempotent

I'm designing a REST-style API for a service that provides analysis of clinical data.  The API allows a user to create a Patient resource.  This resource provides input data to the  server-side analysis.

Creation of a Patient is neither safe nor idempotent (the server assigns an ID) so POST is used,  `POST Patients`

The Patient resource can be large, so it has sub-resources, e.g. Medications, that can be updated.  Updating Medications is idempotent as the entire set of med's will be replaced, so PUT is used.

Clinical analysis is triggered by requesting  `POST /Patients/{patientId}/analysisResults` .  Alternatively, a user can request that analysis results are returned in the response of the POST /Patients request; this saves an additional HTTP round-trip.

My problem is this; users want results of the analysis included in the response to an update (PUT) to `Patient/Medications` - understandable as they don't want to make a second request to retrieve the results. Thus `PUT Patient/Medications` would be idempotent with regards to the Patient resource but not in terms of all resources as a new analysisResults sub-resource will be created.  Should I:

- a) Enable this with a PUT.
- b) Enable this with a POST.
- c) Insist that    a separate call is    required to create new
  analysisResults even though    this will    increase the overall
  response times for the end-user?

Comment: The creation of new analysisResults sub resource need not necessarily mean that request is non idempotent. If multiple PUT requests with the same input data creates the same sub-resource, the call is still idempotent but not safe however if the call creates new sub resource for each PUT with the same data, then it is non-idempotent and also unsafe. See http://sureshkk.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/http-methods-safety-idempotency/ for more on the difference between safety and idempotency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option C if you wish to remain RESTful.

Options A and B will most likely weaken the properties that REST is designed to give you, caching is the one that comes directly to mind.

If this is HTML based, the response will include a link to the analysisReport resource to allow the user to drive the application to somewhere useful.